# Change height of plot (inside chart) in PowerPoint chart

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

Will be great to get help,
i've been trying to figure out a way to change height of a plot  inside chart in PowerPoint slide, i got a code by which we can change the dimensions of chart, but not plot size.
Can anyone help ..!!

```
Sub AllChartsResize()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sr As Series
Dim chrt As Chart

'r converts cm to points
r = 28.3464567

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasChart Then
            
                shp.Height = 15 * r
                shp.Width = 26 * r
                shp.Left = 7 * r
                shp.Top = 2 * r
            End If
            
   
    Next shp
    Next sld

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the PlotArea and can be accessed:

```
If shp.HasChart Then
    Dim pa as PlotArea: set pa = shp.Chart.PlotArea
    pa.Height etc.
```

Now you can change its dimensions as you did with the Shape..

Comment: The dimension properties for PlotArea are actually PlotArea.InsideHeight, .InsideLeft, .InsideTop and .InsideWidth. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.plotarea

Comment: @JohnKorchok, the Inside properties are there to draw other objects inside the plotarea as they give you a relation to the scale you have to draw in. For the purpose above, the "normal" properties are fine